# Using timestampdiff with query builder codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get a time difference from data using the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function, but this time i want to use a pure query builder in codeigniter

```
$this->db->select("TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, (".$this->db->select('payment_date')."), (".$this->db->select('download_date').")))",FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('transaksi');
return $query;
```

I've tried the code above, but it shows an error like this :

> Severity: 4096 Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_driver could not
>   be converted to string

and like this :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '), ())) FROM `transaksi`' at line 1
>
> SELECT payment_date, download_date, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, (), ())) FROM
>   transaksi

is there any solution to get the data?

Comment: shouldn't that be just timestampdiff then the column name, no need to use the select method, unless you need some subquery on that its really not correct then

Comment: so... are my query its wrong or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
 $this->db->select("payment_date, download_date, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, payment_date, download_date)",FALSE);
    $query = $this->db->get('transaksi');
    return $query->result();
```

Comment: i think it will gonna works.. i try it later . thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sub Query not necessary there.

```
$this->db->select("payment_date, download_date, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, payment_date, download_date)",FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('transaksi');
return $query->result();
```

Comment: i think it will gonna works.. i try it later . thank you